# azure functions unable to scaffold dbcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

Using VS 2019, .net core 2.1 and 3.1 I tried to create a map of existing db.

I executed the following npm commands

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 3.1.1
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 3.1.1

Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourservername;Database=yourDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

Got the following error:

> Error:   An assembly specified in the application dependencies
> manifest (FunctionApp1.deps.json) was not found:
> package: 'FunctionApp1', version: '1.0.0'
> path: 'FunctionApp1.dll'

I tried to create a Class Library that executes that NPM above and reference it from my azure function as a workaround. However, whenever I run the method (eg: function1), it generates the following error message

> *An unhandled host error has occurred. [17/02/2020 12:42:30 PM] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: 'Function1' can't be invoked from Azure
> WebJobs SDK. Is it missing Azure WebJobs SDK attributes?*

can someone please help?

screenshot as per below[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14679#issuecomment-550245010).

go to your `.csproj` file and have the following tag:

```cs
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent" Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT' ">
    <Exec Command="copy /Y &quot;$(TargetDir)bin\*.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)*.dll&quot;&#xD;&#xA;" />
</Target>
```

go th nuget command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.2.1
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Version 2.2.1
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.2.1
 Scaffold-DbContext "Server=yourservername;Database=yourdbname;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

And then do not forget to build the project.

It works on mine